# После установки Blackarch на дэсктоп не работает i3wm

Tags: linux, unix, archlinux, live-usb

Поставил Blackarch на дэсктоп. Установил i3wm, reboot и залогинился, а оно не работает от слова совсем - не реагирует на клавиатуру никаким образом и ни на одну клавишу, только мышь. А устанавливал только i3wm. Приходится перезагружаться и опять входить в тайловый оконный менеджер и опять ребутаться. Другие DE (awesome, fluxbox) есть в списке, при выборе, но не работают. Можно как то используя Blackarch Live (и консоль) переустановить DE? Или в i3wm подправить конфиги? И рутовый /dev/sdaXY был зашифрован (crypto_LUKS) при установке.

Comment: Можно. Тоже можно. Так а в чём вопрос?

Comment: Так собственно как это сделать практически?

Comment: У вас слишком много вопросов в одном постинге. Разбейте задачу на подзадачи. Шаг первый: загрузка в чистую консоль (полно ответов в интернете на эту тему). Шаг второй: подключение к сети. Шаг третий: установка, переустановка, обновление.